# Áudio descrição em videos player- HTML 5

Tags: html5, html5-audio, áudio, acessibilidade, reprodutor-de-video

Estou vendo para implementar áudio descrição nos vídeos na empresa onde trabalho, no primeiro momento pensei em criamos 2 vídeos e um botão no player para trocar para o vídeo com Áudio B com a descrição, mas não sei se essa seria a melhor forma, tendo em vista que nós podemos adicionar mais de uma trilha de áudio em um vídeo. Minha pergunta seria qual a melhor forma para implementar essa task? Existe alguma forma de um player HTML 5 navegar por faixas de audio de uma video?

Comment: Se você tem a possibilidade de utilizar dois vídeos, não seria mais simples ter a versão original e a segunda opção com a áudio descrição?
Mas eu entendi o seu problema e é uma questão bem interessante, o suporte a audio tracks no elemento video.

Comment: sim exato, queria algo com tracks... mas pelo que vi o netflix utiliza 2 vídeos...